# Forminator + Stripe - delayed credit card charging

Tags: stripe-payments

Is there a way to collect credit card information in Stripe without charging? Like delayed billing using just Forminator's native Stripe field?

We want to collect credit card details up front but not charge until the 4th session because we have a trial period and don't want to charge until the end of the trial period.

Also, how do I pass coupon information to Stripe using Forminator?

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to ask for assistance from the Forminator [developers or community](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/forminator/) to accomplish this.

Generally speaking, Stripe supports [saving card details for later](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse) through the Setup Intents API. You can also [authorize payments and capture them later](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/capture-later) (within 7 days) if that is applicable.

I do not know how Forminator works or whether the plugin supports these features.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll go to Forminator but I'll also see if I can get away with modifying the metadata forminator sends to Stripe